# Decomposing a number into primes

Tags: c, primes

I have written the following code to decompose a number into primes. The problem is that it takes so much time and I have no idea why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int prime (int n){int j=2; 
if (n==2) return 1;
while(j<(n/2)){ 
if(n%j==0) { return 0;}
j=j+1;
}return 1;}

int expotent (int n,int p){int j=0;
while((n%p)==0){
j=j+1;
p=p*p;
}
return j;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {int h=0,n=1,k=1,t=0 ;
scanf("%d",&n);
int j=n;
while(k!=n){
if(expotent(n,j)!=0 & prime(j)==1)
{
    if(t==0) {t=1; printf("%d^%d",j,expotent(n,j));
for( h<expotent(n,j); h++;){k=k*j;} 
    }
else {
printf("*%d^%d",j,expotent(n,j));
for( h<expotent(n,j); h++;){k=k*j;}}
}
j=j-1;
}
return 0;}
```

Comment: In your opinion, do you think your code is readable as formatted as it is ?

Comment: Are you trying to write for C or C++? You have both tagged

Comment: it is C. but well, you can run it as C++ as well I suppose.

Comment: It could be a good idea to tell us : 1) how your program is supposed to be used 2) how your program is supposed to work : documentation of the different functions and of the whole algorithm.

Comment: @Iman but you cannot run all C++ as C. So if we give you responses with C++ specific code, then it wont be useful to you as part of your C project :p

Comment: I got it! For large numbers, `b*b` is too large to be considered an `int`, so the program returns `b` itself.

Answer (score 3):

Before you can hope to understand what the code does and why it performs badly, you first have to be able to read it easily.  For your benefit and for the benefit of other reviewers, here is your code, with no changes other than whitespace:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int prime(int n) {
    int j = 2;
    if (n == 2) return 1;
    while (j < (n/2)) { 
        if (n % j == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        j = j + 1;
    }
    return 1;
}

int expotent(int n, int p){
    int j = 0;
    while ((n % p) == 0) {
        j = j + 1;
        p = p * p;
    }
    return j;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int h = 0, n = 1, k = 1, t = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int j = n;
    while (k != n) {
        if (expotent(n, j) != 0 & prime(j) == 1) {
            if (t == 0) {
                t = 1;
                printf("%d^%d", j, expotent(n,j));
                for (h < expotent(n,j); h++; ) {
                    k = k * j;
                } 
            } else {
                printf("*%d^%d", j, expotent(n,j));
                for (h < expotent(n,j); h++; ) {
                    k = k * j;
                }
            }
        }
        j = j - 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now you can see what the branching and looping structure looks like!

Comment: I was about to post the same comment ! Thanks for saving everyone some time.

Comment: Well.. it is still not readable enough.

Comment: thanks a lot! im so sorry for it being unclear. let me explain; I defined two functions, prime, is used to determine if a number is prime or not. and expotent, which takes two numbers as argument, and returns the power of the second number in the prime decomposition of the first(like how many times can I divide the first by second?). the rest is just checking if a number j divides the number I want to decompose, if it does, AND is prime, I write it down.